# Multicast server c and .bat file to open it

Tags: c, batch-file, server, multicast

Recently I have been struggling with servers for the first time:

The case is: I have a software (Motive from Optitrack) that provides a streaming of data via multicasting.

I have tried to modify a previous program, it can be build but I have some issues to solve:

1º- I want a .bat file to automatically open the server with the argc parameters, I have made one, but it doesn't work. The code is at the end.

2º When executing the .exe file, the console bips for a moment and closes. I suppose that it is because it returns -1, but maybe there is some error in the code.

I'm on Windows 10, using Code::Blocks and Gcc compiler.

The server code is:

```
#include <sys/types.h>  /* for type definitions */
#include <winsock2.h>   /* for win socket API calls */
#include <ws2tcpip.h>   /* for win socket structs */
#include <stdio.h>      /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for atoi() */
#include <string.h>     /* for strlen() */

#define MAX_LEN  1024   /* maximum receive string size */
#define MIN_PORT 1051   /* minimum port allowed */
#define MAX_PORT 1051 /* maximum port allowed */
#define NUM_RIG_OBJ 2


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int sock;                     /* socket descriptor */
  int flag_on = 1;              /* socket option flag */
  struct sockaddr_in mc_addr;   /* socket address structure */
  char recv_str[MAX_LEN+1];     /* buffer to receive string */
  int recv_len, ID ;                 /* length of string received */
  struct ip_mreq mc_req;        /* multicast request structure */
  char* mc_addr_str   ;         /* multicast IP address */
  unsigned short mc_port;       /* multicast port */
  struct sockaddr_in from_addr; /* packet source */
  unsigned int from_len;        /* source addr length */
  WSADATA wsaData;              /* Windows socket DLL structure */
float xa,ya,za,qx,qy,qz,qw;


  /* validate number of arguments */

  if (argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "Usage: %s <Multicast IP> <Multicast Port>\n",
            argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }

  mc_addr_str = argv[1];      /* arg 1: multicast ip address */
  mc_port = atoi(argv[2]);    /* arg 2: multicast port number */



  /* validate the port range */
  if ((mc_port < MIN_PORT) || (mc_port > MAX_PORT)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid port number argument %d.\n",
            mc_port);
    fprintf(stderr, "Valid range is between %d and %d.\n",
            MIN_PORT, MAX_PORT);
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Load Winsock 2.0 DLL */
  if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsaData) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup() failed");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* create socket to join multicast group on */
  if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0) {
    perror("socket() failed");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* set reuse port to on to allow multiple binds per host */
  if ((setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&flag_on,
       sizeof(flag_on))) < 0) {
    perror("setsockopt() failed");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* construct a multicast address structure */
  memset(&mc_addr, 0, sizeof(mc_addr));
  mc_addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
  mc_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  mc_addr.sin_port        = htons(mc_port);

  /* bind to multicast address to socket */
  if ((bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &mc_addr,
       sizeof(mc_addr))) < 0) {
    perror("bind() failed");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* construct an IGMP join request structure */
  mc_req.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(mc_addr_str);
  mc_req.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

  /* send an ADD MEMBERSHIP message via setsockopt */
  if ((setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,
       (char*) &mc_req, sizeof(mc_req))) < 0) {
    perror("setsockopt() failed");
    exit(1);
  }

        int md=recv_str[0];
      char *ptr = recv_str;
         float x[NUM_RIG_OBJ]= {0};
         float y[NUM_RIG_OBJ]= {0};
         float z[NUM_RIG_OBJ]= {0};
         float q1[NUM_RIG_OBJ]= {0};
         float q2[NUM_RIG_OBJ]= {0};
         float q3[NUM_RIG_OBJ]= {0};
         float q4[NUM_RIG_OBJ]= {0};

  for (;;) {          /* loop forever */

    /* clear the receive buffers & structs */
    memset(recv_str, 0, sizeof(recv_str));
    from_len = sizeof(from_addr);
    memset(&from_addr, 0, from_len);

    /* block waiting to receive a packet */
    if ((recv_len = recvfrom(sock, recv_str, MAX_LEN, 0,
         (struct sockaddr*)&from_addr, &from_len)) < 0) {
      perror("recvfrom() failed");
      exit(1);
    }

    /* output received string */
    printf("Received %d bytes from %s: ", recv_len,
           inet_ntoa(from_addr.sin_addr));
    printf("%s", recv_str);

            // rigid body pos/ori

            if (md==7){
        for (int i=0;i<NUM_RIG_OBJ;i++){

            memcpy(&ID, ptr, 4); ptr += 4;
            memcpy(&xa, ptr, 4); ptr += 4;
            memcpy(&ya, ptr, 4); ptr += 4;
            memcpy(&za, ptr, 4); ptr += 4;
            memcpy(&qx, ptr, 4); ptr += 4;
            memcpy(&qy, ptr, 4); ptr += 4;
            memcpy(&qz, ptr, 4); ptr += 4;
            memcpy(&qw, ptr, 4); ptr += 4;
            printf("ID : %d\n", ID);
            printf("pos: [%3.4f,%3.4f,%3.4f]\n", xa,ya,za);
            printf("ori: [%3.4f,%3.4f,%3.4f,%3.4f]\n", qx,qy,qz,qw);


            x[i]=xa;
            y[i]=ya;
            z[i]=za;
            q1[i]=qx;
            q2[i]=qy;
            q3[i]=qz;
            q4[i]=qw;

              ptr = recv_str;
              memcpy(ptr, &i, 4); ptr += 4;
              memcpy(ptr, &x[i], 4); ptr += 4;
              memcpy(ptr, &y[i], 4); ptr += 4;
              memcpy(ptr, &z[i], 4); ptr += 4;
              memcpy(ptr, &q1[i], 4); ptr += 4;
              memcpy(ptr, &q2[i], 4); ptr += 4;
              memcpy(ptr, &q3[i], 4); ptr += 4;
              memcpy(ptr, &q4[i], 4); ptr += 4;
            }



  }



  /* send a DROP MEMBERSHIP message via setsockopt */
  if ((setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_DROP_MEMBERSHIP,
       (void*) &mc_req, sizeof(mc_req))) < 0) {
    perror("setsockopt() failed");
    exit(1);
  }

  closesocket(sock);
  WSACleanup();  /* Cleanup Winsock */

}
return 0;
}
```

---

and the .bat file is

@echo off

```
echo Opening server...
cd C:\Users\Optitrack\Desktop\Conrado\mcreceive
start mcreceive.exe 259.44.99.107 1051
```

---

Any piece of advice would be much appreciated.
thank you

Comment: Now is the time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Wait: does this server run Windows or Linux?

Comment: Because you use `start` to start the program, a separate window is opened for it.  That window will close as soon as the program finishes, so if an error message prints you won't be able to see it. Start up a Command Prompt and run the program manually from there *without* a .bat file and *without* `start` first.  That way you can see the output even after it finishes and debug from there.

Comment: the posted code should be using `recv_len` to NUL terminate the buffer `recv_str`  otherwise the call to `printf()` will perform undefined behavior.

Comment: at this point in the program: `int md=recv_str[0];` the buffer `recv_str` contains what ever trash was on the stack where the buffer is located/  so this statement: `if (md==7){` is expecting some random value from the stack to be 7,  That is VERY unlikely to be the case.

Comment: regarding: `for (;;) { `  what are you expecting will cause that loop to exit?

Comment: after the initial terminal window closes, have you checked the list of active functions (accessible by <ctrl><alt><delete> ) to see if the server is still running?

Comment: suggest, when running the program to redirect the output to a file, then you can `type` the file to see what was actually output